# SVG background size differs in Internet Explorer 9 & 10

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I've been trying to use a SVG as a background-image for an element scaling it using the `background-size`-property. This works great in most current browsers, but Internet Explorer seems to misinterpret the values, showing the image in a much smaller size when I use only one value, and an incorrect ratio with two values.

I've put up an example at http://jsfiddle.net/c7DEw/1/

The width and height of the svg have been set to 100%. I figured it had something to do with the `viewBox` and `enable-background` properties, but these don't seem to have any effect.

This happens both in Internet Explorer 9 and 10.

Has anybody encountered this behaviour before? And if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: 7,8,9,10...which one?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ but I guess should work maybe is a browser feature issue.

Comment: I read Chris' article earlier today and tested his version in IE, which seemed to work as expected. While he doesn't have an example of the background version up, the code seems to be mostly the same.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this? I've come across the same problem.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem was caused by something I was misremembering from an article. I had changed the width and height of the SVG to 100% (see the JS part of my fiddle) which Internet Explorer seems to interpret different from other browsers.

Comment: Thanks. What works for me is, i have to have a size, width and height, declared in the svg, it doesn't seem to matter what the size is as i can change it via css. Just simply declaring a size means that ie will behave the same as other browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem with svg files generated by Illustrator for use as background images, and after much trial and error the fix seems to be just to edit each svg file and declare the width and height of the svg as attributes, e.g. `<svg width="32px" height="128px">` (something that Illustrator doesn't set but Sketch does). This caused the svgs to behave the same in IE 10/11 as they do in Chrome/FF.

Comment: Thanks: I just ran into the same problem with the same fix. My SVG files had viewBox and displayed considerably smaller than specified until I added height and width attributes to the <svg> tag.

Comment: Fixed this for me in IE9

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue for me. I also needed to match the width and height values to those in the viewbox attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem again with another projects. I copied assets individually from an Illustrator design to a new file and changed the artboard to perfectly line up with its bounding box. I then included the SVGs via the CSS background-property and noticed the smaller display size in both IE10 and IE11.

After then reopening the assets in Illustrator, copying them over to Sketch and exporting them to SVG this behavior disappeared.

It looks like Illustrator is creating an Artboard (or container) of an incorrect size, which throws of the dimensions. But I've googled this question multiple times and have not found anyone else encountering this issue, so it may be something I'm doing wrong. But the process is so straightforward that I can't imagine what it could be.