# background-size not working in IE 9/10

Tags: css

I have come across a problem with background-size IE 9/10

```
.svg {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 120px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,...);
    background-size: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a394Z/5/

If the element with the background does not have a defined width, the size of the background seems to default to size of the original svg image.

In this example, the image is rendered at 16x16px rather than 100x100px.

I have been working around this issue by using an :after pseudo element. But am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `background-size` should work in IE9/10 so maybe it's a problem with SVG. I've used [this polyfil](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) to get `background-size` to work in IE8, maybe it can help you here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092114/background-size-differs-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the X and Y even they are similar: `background-size: 100px 100px`

Hope it helps.